# qtextedit not redrawing properly after adding image

Tags: qt, qtextedit

I have a qtextedit with small placeholder images that users click on to load their own images, which can be much larger. When the new image is loaded the qtextedit sort of updates and shows part of the new image but it fails to add scrollbars (which may not be present before changing the image). I believe as a side effect, I'm no longer able to move to view the text before the image. I can move the cursor but it's not properly scrolling the window.

If I manually resize the main window the qtextedit then redraws properly, adding necessary scrollbars. How can I force this behavior programmatically? I've tried textEdit->update() and processEvents() but still don't get the desired behavior.

Setup:
Windows XP
MS VS2010
qt 4.8

Comment: This looks like a Qt bug. You should create a small testcase (single file, a few dozen lines) and submit it.